# how to do this with pure mysql?

Tags: mysql

If mysql record with condition exists-update it,else  create new record

Comment: Can you give an example? Perhaps User Defined Variables would be helpful.

Comment: Could you tell us what your condition is? This might make a difference to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know what a condition is, but what is the specific condition you have in mind? Some are easier to handle than others.

Comment: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE are what i want to find.thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: That is ok but will only do what the OP wanted if there is a unique index on those columns; it can't be used for arbitrary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) instead of INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `REPLACE INTO` for that with the syntax of `INSERT INTO`. This way MySQL will invoke an `UPDATE` whenever there's a fictive constraint violation.

Be aware that this construct is MySQL-specific, so your query ain't going to work whenever you switch from DB.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?